# HibernateException Missing Table

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, h2

I have this project setup where i am trying to use JPA with Hibernate as provider to store data in my local h2 database. Its all configured as part of my spring project and I am using tomcat as my server. Now for the last week or so I have been breaking my head over this one basic issue that is stopping me from having my application work successfully. And that is ability of the application to communicate with my database. Initially I had the hibernate property hbm2ddl set to create-update. With this configuration, although the application was starting successfully, no data was being persisted to the local H2 database. But the point to be noted here is that the data is persisted within the JVM. So I am able to retrieve what was stored. Please note that this was happening in spite of me not running the h2 database in memory mode. Now after some research I realized, I should have the hbm2ddl property set to validate, because I was already creating the database schema separately using the H2 console. But here is where I am getting this hibernate exception of Missing Table. I did some digging by debugging into the 3rd party  hibernate, c3p0 and h2 jars I was using but I have literally hit wall. I can actually see the JdbcDatabaseMetaData class in H2 driver jar creating a prepared statement, But when that statement is executed, it returns empty result set. Well, to check if there is any connectivity or query related issue, I took that exact query and executed it through a stand alone program that uses simple H2 Jdbc connection. And surprisingly I am able to retrieve the exact data whose absence is causing the 'Missing Table' hibernate exception.

Does anyone know why this thing is caused? The drivers work fine, I assuming hibernate has nothing to do with it. That leaves me suspecting that there is something about tomcat which is precluding this communication with the database. Any comment, hint, tip at this point will be much appreciated.

Below is some basic configuration .

Persistence configuration

```
<!-- datasource -->
<bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- DB connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${db.user:}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password:}" />

    <!-- Pool sizing properties -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${db.pool.initialSize:5}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${db.pool.maxSize:25}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${db.pool.minSize:0}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${db.pool.maxStatements:10}" />

    <!-- Connection testing and acquisition properties -->
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${db.con.testPeriod:30}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${db.con.testQuery:select 1 from dual}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${db.con.acquireIncrement:5}" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${db.con.retryAttempts:0}" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="${db.con.retryDelay:3000}" />

    <!-- JMX name -->
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="Datasource" />

    <!-- Debugging options -->
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${db.con.unreturnedTimeout:0}" />
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${db.con.debugUnreturned:false}" />
</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.omni" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.hib.dialect}</prop>
          <!--   <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${db.hib.schema:SVC_APP}</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">${db.hib.isolationLevel:4}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">${db.hib.fetchSize:50}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${db.hib.maxFetchDepth:3}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">${db.hib.defBatchSize:8}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hib.ddl:none}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${db.hib.genStats:true}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${db.hib.formatSql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor">com.omni.core.support.hibernate.AuditInterceptor</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>   
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">DEALS</prop>             -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

This is the entity file for which I get the Missing Table error message.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerEt  {  
private  String id;
private  String lastName;   
private  String firstName;  
private  String middleName; 

@Id
@Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
@Column(name="MIDDLE_NAME")
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
}
```

Comment: Can show us some code  and configuration. Also try stripping down the application. Have just once single entity try crud operations.

Comment: I have added the details. Even before I try to perform any crud operations, the application throws error when it starts in tomcat. The error is missing table customer.

Comment: Try one thing  initially set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to update. Let hibernate create tables for you. Then set it back to none and see if it works.

Comment: I tried this, but when I connect to the database using H2 console, I do not see those tables or the data inserted using crud operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding to my question. I finally figured out the issue with my setup. H2 was being run embedded mode. I was assuming that even with embedded mode, the data should persist even after the JVM is brought down. However, that was evidently not true for me. So when I changed it over to the TCP/server mode, it all works smoothly without any issues.

If anyone else is facing the same problem, please put a comment here and I would be happy to help.